# Create custom connection/ non-fully connected layers in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

[image: A NN with first layer is fully connected and second is custom connection]

As shown in the figure, it is a 3 layer with NN, namely input layer, hidden layer and output layer. I want to design the NN(in PyTorch, just the arch) where the input to hidden layer is fully-connected. However, from hidden layer to output, the first two neurons of the hidden layer should be connected to first neuron of the output layer, second two should be connected to the second in the output layer and so on. How shall this should be designed ?

```
from torch import nn
layer1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
layer2 = ??????
```

Answer (score 4):

As [@Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2169599/jan) said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72726119/6331369), you can overload [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) and provide a point-wise mask to mask the interaction you want to avoid having. Remember that a fully connected layer is merely a matrix multiplication with an optional additive bias.

Looking at its [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L48), we can do:

```
class MaskedLinear(nn.Linear):
    def __init__(self, *args, mask, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mask = mask

    def forward(self, input):
        return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)*self.mask
```

Having `F` defined as [`torch.nn.functional`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html)

Considering the constraint you have given to the second layer:

> the first two neurons of the hidden layer should be connected to the first neuron of the output layer

It seems you are looking for this pattern:

```
tensor([[1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.]])
```

Which can be obtained using [`torch.block_diag`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.block_diag.html):

```
mask = torch.block_diag(*[torch.ones(2,1),]*output_size)
```

Having this, you can define your network as:

```
net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size),
                    MaskedLinear(hidden_size, output_size, mask))
```

---

If you feel like it, you can even implement it inside the custom layer:

```
class LocalLinear(nn.Linear):
    def __init__(self, *args, kernel_size=2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        assert self.in_features == kernel_size*self.out_features
        self.mask = torch.block_diag(*[torch.ones(kernel_size,1),]*self.out_features)

def forward(self, input):
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)*self.mask
```

And defining it like so:

```
net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size),
                    LocalLinear(hidden_size, output_size))
```

Comment: My input size is (batch_size, 100) and my mask is (100, 10),
The line: 
out = F.linear(input*self.mask, self.weight, self.bias)
throwing error:

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (100) must match the size of tensor b (10) at non-singleton dimension 1

Comment: You're right, there was an issue. The mask should be applied after the linear layer is infered  on, not before. See my edit above.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. The weight matrix is the one that needs to be masked, not the output of weight*input + bias. After the multiply has happened, we cannot remove the unwanted interactions.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `nn.Linear` directly, create a weights tensor `weight` and a mask tensor `mask` that masks those weights that you do not intend to use. Then you use `torch.nn.functional.linear(input, weight * mask)` (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.linear.html) to forward the second layer. Note that this is implemented in your `torch.nn.Module`'s `forward` function. The weight needs to be registered as a parameter to your `nn.Module` so that it's recognized by `nn.Module.parameters()`. See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.register_parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Ivan's general approach (masking the fully connected layer) may work with modifications as in my comment, but it adds a lot of useless computation!

It's probably best to write a custom layer here, with a weight matrix of shape `(2, hidden_size//2)`. Then reshape the input to the layer from  output of the hidden layer from `(hidden_size)` to `(hidden_size//2, 2)` and do the matrix multiply.

Something like this (untested):

```py
class MyLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.weight = torch.zeros(2, in_channels // 2)
        self.bias = torch.zeros(in_channels // 2)

    def forward(self, inp):
        return torch.matmul(inp.reshape(-1, inp.shape[-1]//2, 2), self.weight) + self.bias
```

Comment: You should register `weight` and `bias` as an `nn.Parameter`. How do you make sure the gradients are back propagated correctly? Does `matmul` automatically create a `grad_fn`?